# Feature request: Link to drafts from profile page

Tags: feature-request

If I start writing an answer and then leave the page, when I next return to that question, my partially written answer is saved in the answer field. This is convenient as it allows me to return to answers in progress.

However, if I go away long enough that the question scrolls of the front page, I then have to dig around to find it again. I propose that there be a tab in my profile page, visible only to me, which links to answer drafts that I have not submitted.

I realize that there are work-arounds: I could use the "favorite" star to tag questions that I have left drafts in, or e-mail myself links to those questions. But I think that a simple page where I can see my answers in progress would be more convenient.

Comment: I wonder, are the drafts stored on the server or locally?

Comment: @Antonio: You get one draft (per site), and it is stored on the server.

Comment: [Source of Asaf's statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238). Adding a tab for a single link looks like too much. If the site supported multiple drafts, the tab would make sense. But requests for multiple drafts have been repeatedly [shot down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113416).

Comment: @user103402: Where do you see a request for a tab? Not all links in the profile are tabs, some are just links...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I remember seeing it somewhere in "I propose that there be a tab in my profile page", but that may have been an illusion.

Comment: Yes ! I was about to ask for the same when I found your post :) there is also the solution to have an unique draft, to save formulas